# JSP session.invalidate() vs request.logout()

Tags: jsp, session, tomcat, logout, invalidation

I have a SignOut button on my jsp page. (Tomcat 8.0.15)

```
session.invalidate()
```

or

```
request.logout()
```

which one is better for signing-out/terminating the session, what is the main difference? Should I use both?

Comment: And how to check if session.invalidate() and request.logout() were successful? that is true?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `logout()` clears the identity information in the request but doesn't affect the session
- `invalidate()` invalidates the session but doesn't affect the identity information in the request.

I think you should use both.